# Updating Dataset after a database column value update

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I would like to know a thing if thst is possible.. let's put that I have a database with 3 column (name, last name and age) that obviously will be type: varchar, varchar and int.

then on visual studio I create a datagridrow with a dataset for automatically retrieve values from database so in my grid I will see this:

```
Mark  //Name
Wally //Last name
38    //Age
```

And untill here all is easy, but if for some reason I change the value of age from int to varchar and add a vale like: "December" when I open my datagrid I should see

```
Mark  //Name
Wally //Last name
December   //Age converted from int to varchar only for this example
```

Instead I get an exception that says: "impossible to store a String in the column 'Age' because type is int", So for fixing this problem a person has got only 2 chances

```
1) Delete the Dataset on the form designer and create back another one;
2) Going in the code behind of the dataset (DataSet.Designer) and manually change all the values of the column Age from int to varchar.
```

Both are boring solutions anyway, is it possible isn't there a way to automatically update the dataset after that a changed is made inside the database?

Ty very much guys and Merry Christmas.

Comment: I forgotten to say that obviously I created a BindingSource in the properties of the Datagrid so it automatically fills the grid with the db's values

Comment: Ok I fixed it very easy just go to the .xsd and then change the values of the column there!